# Derivative of a strange integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Consider the following function:
$$
K(t) = \int_0^t \frac{d}{dt} [G(t-p)] F(p) dp
$$
I am wondering about the outcome of K'(t). My guess is
$$
K'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}G(t)|_{t=0} F(t) 
$$

Comment: Are $ t$ and $t'$ independant ?

Comment: Could you add parenthesis to make it clearer.

Comment: yes, they are. I have changed the notation

Comment: You had to write partial derivation since there are two varables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look at the function
$$
K_2(x,y) = \int_0^y G'(x-p)F(p)\ dp.
$$
Then we are looking at the derivative of the composition of $t\mapsto (x,y)$ with $K_2$. The chain rule then says
$$
\frac{d K}{dt}= \frac{\partial K_2}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial t } +\frac{\partial K_2}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial t } =  \frac{\partial K_2}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial K_2}{\partial y}.
$$
Now if we assume that $F$ and $G$ are nice enough,
$$
 \frac{\partial K_2}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_0^y G'(x-p)F(p)\ dp = \int_0^y G''(x-p)F(p)\ dp.
$$
And
$$
 \frac{\partial K_2}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_0^y G'(x-p)F(p)\ dp =G'(x-y)F(y) - G'(x)F(0).
$$
All together:
$$
\frac{dK}{dt} = \int_0^y G''(x-p)F(p)\ dp + G'(x-y)F(y) - G'(x)F(0) = $$
$$=\int_0^t G''(t-p)F(p)\ dp + G'(0)F(t) - G'(t)F(0).
$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Your integral has the form
$$K(t)=\int_0^tH(t,p)F(p)dp$$

For $t\ne 0$, we put $ p=ut.$. it becomes

$$K(t)=\int_0^1uH(t,ut)F(ut)dt$$